# Symfony scaffolding error

Tags: php, symfony1

I have installed symfony 1.0.22. I am following the tutorial on symfony-project.org
So far entering in CLI the code below

```
safarov@Safarov:/var/www/test$ php symfony propel-generate-crud frontend post Post
```

gives this error:

```
[sfInitializationException]                 
Unable to scaffold unexistant model "Post"
```

what is the reason?

Thanks

Comment: You should *not* be starting a sf1.0 project now. Use 1.4 or even better: Symfony 2.0 (that's been stable for a while now).

Comment: yeah, I know and it would be better. However, I learn it for the project that had been written by using sf1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. It's because creole used in symfony is not compatible with PHP 5.3.x

There was error when I try "symfony propel-build-model":

```
[phingcall] Unable to return 'affix' for unknown CreoleType:
```

Removing self::TEXT from the array in CreoleType.php solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the `Post` model doesn't exist. It's probably due to a lack in your `schema.yml`.
Can you paste it ? You should read the following doc: http://www.symfony-project.org/askeet/1_0/en/2.

Before to generate a CRUD module, you have to build your model:

```
$ symfony propel-build-model
```

Then, you'll have to build SQL and to insert it:

```
$ symfony propel-build-sql
$ symfony propel-insert-sql
```